# How are questions with equal votes sorted?

Tags: support, questions, sorting

I just noticed that when you sort *questions* by votes, the questions with the same amount of votes are not ordered randomly.

I am not saying that this is bad or wrong, I just want to know what is the criteria to put one above the other(s)?

Also I am a bit curious on why they didn't apply the same feature that is being used to sort answers with the same amount of votes, is there a particular reason or did they just forgot to apply it on questions too?

Comment: Given all the irritations that random answer sorting has caused on (rare) questions with multiple pages of answers, I shudder to imagine the horrors that would result from applying it to questions...

Comment: Good catch, couldn't see any pattern as well. Appears to be "fixed random", lol!

Comment: I'd expect it to be random, but cached.

Comment: @Oded good point, this fits exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code from [Marc's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) amazing tag engine when sorting by votes, where `x` and `y` are questions:

```
// question score desc
int delta = y.Score.CompareTo(x.Score);

// tie? then by aggregate answer score desc
if (delta == 0) delta = y.AnswerScore.CompareTo(x.AnswerScore);

// tie? fallback to question creation date desc
return delta == 0 ? y.Id.CompareTo(x.Id) : delta;
```